# Issues FindRootPlot command

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I've had some fun playing around with `FindRootPlot` for a simple system of equations:

```
<< Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`
f[1] = Sin[x[1] + x[2]]
f[2] = Cos[x[1] - x[2]]
F = Table[f[i], {i, 1, 2}]

guess[1] = 1;
guess[2] = -1;

Xinsert = Table[{x[i], guess[i]}, {i, 1, 2}]

FindRootPlot[F, Xinsert, Method -> {"Newton", 
"StepControl{"LineSearch","MaxRelativeStepSize" -> .1}}]
```

Which gives a plot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the following:

```
{{x[1] -> 0.785398, x[2] -> -0.785398}, {"Steps" -> 5,"Residual" -> 5, "Jacobian" -> 4},
```

But when I tried applying it to a larger matrix it seems to no longer work. Given:

```
dim = 8; 

test4 ={0.3125 z[5] + 0.4375 z[6] + 0.0706277 z[7] + 0.101342 z[8], 0.5 z[7] + 1.   
z[8], -0.961887 z[1] - 1.35898 z[2] - 0.29427 z[3] - 0.415442 z[4], -3.30241 z[1] - 
6.60482 z[2], -2.77806 z[5] - 3.90146 z[6] - 0.671632 z[7] - 0.943006 z[8] + 1.875 
z[1] z[9] + 2.625 z[2] z[9] + z[3] (-1.83751 + 1.875 z[9]) + z[4] (-2.58057 + 2.625 
z[9]), -1.95073 z[5] - 2.77806 z[6] - 0.471503 z[7] - 0.671632 z[8] + 1.3125 z[1] 
z[9] + 1.875 z[2] z[9] + z[3] (-1.29029 + 1.3125 z[9]) + z[4] (-1.83751 + 1.875   
z[9]), z[6] (-10.1813 - 2.54697 z[9]) + z[5] (-7.27566 - 1.83285 z[9]) + 2.42463 
z[1] z[9] + 3.36932 z[2] z[9] + 1.01633 z[7] z[9] + 1.42194 z[8] z[9] + z[3]  
(-2.74994 + 2.42463 z[9]) + z[4] (-3.84816 + 3.36932 z[9]), z[6] (-7.27566 - 1.83285 
z[9]) + z[5] (-5.09064 - 1.27349 z[9]) + 1.68466 z[1] z[9] + 2.42463 z[2] z[9] + 
0.710972 z[7] z[9] + 1.01633 z[8] z[9] + z[3] (-1.92408 + 1.68466 z[9]) + 
z[4] (-2.74994 + 2.42463 z[9]), -1 + z[3]/2 + z[4] + z[5] + z[6]}
```

and

```
Esol2 = AppendTo[Esol, 1]

(* {-5.15989, 2.57995, 12.036, -5.01798, 0.391302, -0.357324,1.70608,     
-0.85304, 1} *)
```

and

```
Dimensions[Esol2]

(* {9} *)
```

I can explain where `Esol` and `test4` come from if needed but I didn't want to clutter the post with too much information. For now I just want to point out that they are lists of length 9.

Now I try to use `FindRootPlot`:

```
F = Table[test4[[i]], {i, 1, dim + 1}];

Dimensions[F]

(* {9} *)

Xinsert = Table[{z[i], Esol[[i]]}, {i, 1, dim + 1}]

(* {{z[1], -5.15989}, {z[2], 2.57995}, {z[3], 12.036}, {z[4], -5.01798},    
{z[5], 0.391302}, {z[6], -0.357324}, {z[7], 1.70608}, {z[8], -0.85304}, {z[9], 1}} *)

Dimensions[Xinsert]

(* {9, 2} *)

FindRootPlot[F, Xinsert,Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> {"LineSearch",   
"MaxRelativeStepSize" -> .1}}]
```

**Which gives me an error about the number of equations not being equal to the number of variables**. But this makes no sense the length of `Xinsert` and `F` are clearly equal. Running the previous command also gives this:

```
FindRoot[Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`Private`obj, {{z[1], -5.15989}, {z[2],     
2.57995}, {z[3],12.036}, {z[4], -5.01798}, {z[5], 0.391302}, {z[6], -0.357324},    
{z[7], 1.70608}, {z[8], -0.85304}, {z[9],1}}, {"Jacobian" -> {"Symbolic", 
EvaluationMonitor :> 
Sow[{{z[1],-5.15989},Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`Private`obj},{Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`Private`j$37945,Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`Private`all$37945}]}, Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> {"LineSearch", "MaxRelativeStepSize" -> 0.1}}, "StepMonitor" :> Sow[{{z[1], -5.15989},    Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`Private`obj}, \
{Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`Private`s$37945, 
 Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`Private`all$37945}], 
  "EvaluationMonitor" :> 
   Sow[{{z[1], -5.15989}, 
 Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`Private`obj}, \
{Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`Private`r$37945, 
 Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`Private`all$37945}]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindRootPlot[]` supports only 1D and 2D problems:

> FindRootPlot[f,{{x,Subscript[x, st]},{y,Subscript[y, st]}},opts]   plot the steps and the points at which the function f and any of its derivatives that were evaluated in FindRoot[f,{{x,Subscript[x, st]},{y,Subscript[y, st]}}], superimposed on a contour plot of the merit function f as a function of x and y; opts may include options from both FindRoot and ContourPlot

How could it plot the problem in more dimensions?

Comment: You can apply `FindRoot` (without the `Plot`) in as many dimensions as needed. Then plot the roots as you wish.

Comment: Crap, I feel like such an idiot. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: @tau1777 If only they give me one cent for each time I feel like that ...